# implicitlyWait() is not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

```
    String baseURL = "http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2";
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(baseURL);

    Select muldrpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("fruits")));

    muldrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("Banana");
    //muldrpdwn.selectByIndex(3);
    muldrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("Orange");
    muldrpdwn.selectByVisibleText("Apple");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;

    muldrpdwn.deselectAll();
```

I want to select multiple text and wait for 10 seconds and the deselect them all.
 selection and deselection is working fine.
 But both are happening like there is no wait inserted which is not as I have inserted 10 seconds wait.
 What's wrong?

Comment: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html this could be helpfull for your 10 seconds wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit wait is ***not*** `Thread.sleep()`. It's being defined one time, and it will cause the driver to wait ***up*** to 10 seconds for the elements to exists in the DOM when trying to locate them (using `driver.findElement`).

From [WebDriver: Advanced Usage](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available

You can use explicit wait with [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for certain condition. If you want to wait full 10 seconds regardless (**NOT** recommended) use `Thread.sleep(10000)`.